# kde (on ubuntu 22.10) - chromium or konsole UIs freeze

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, kde, gui

I am running on kde on a ubuntu 22.10 box (updating since... ubuntu 20.04, perhaps?). I have noticed that every once in a while either konsole or chromium UIs freeze. I can still interact *blindly* on the UI if I click or write stuff but, of course, the UI does not reflect what I do. If I switch to a different virtual desktop and then I come back, I can see the UI reflecting what I did. It is a per-window problem. If I multiple windows open for chromium or konsole, it only affects a given window and the other windows of the same app are not affected.

If I have another app in the same virtual desktop and I switch to it, when I come back to the busted window, it does reflect changes.

Another thing I just tested: If I detach a given tab from konsole, the original window continues to be stuck, but the detached tab starts behaving.

I am using Xorg with nvidia driver.

```
[    14.466] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    14.466] (II) Loading /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
[    14.469] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    14.469]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[    14.469]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
```

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 2):

When it happens, try pressing Alt + Shift + F12 two times, this combination restarts the compositor which means it should help.

I feel like this issue has to do something with kwin directly, happens to me on every 22.10 installation I have (both on AMD and Intel GPUs).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Will be testing it.

Comment: @eftshift0 I'm curious, did it help to alleviate the symptoms in your case?

Comment: Nothing works as well as _asking a question in unix.stackexchange.com_.... haven't seen the bug since. When I see it pop up again, will try this trick and will provide feedback. Thanks for asking @bdzkv

Comment: Didn't work, unfortunately.